# openSL ES emulator for PC

Tags: android-ndk, opensl

I have openSL ES working for my android NDK.
Is there a way to make my openSL ES code emulated on the PC ? Can someone provide suggestions as to what will be the best alternatives if emulation is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use Genymotion.  It's suitable for realtime audio with OpenSL ES.

Answer (score 0):

just use android sdk emulator. I have a project with opensl run in android sdk emulator (android 4.2 version) just fine